# How to extend a Ionic component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

How can I extend a `<ion-item>` Ionic component

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
      <img src="img/thumbnail-totoro.png">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2>My Neighbor Totoro</h2>
    <p>Hayao Miyazaki • 1988</p>
    <button ion-button clear item-end>View</button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Extending the component to let's say a custom one `<custom-ion-item>` and extending the logic and template?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please explain why do you want to do that? If you want to create a custom designed `ion-list`, you can style the inner components. I do not feel it as a good idea to override the basic things without any strong reason.